# How to create a single series bar graph with legends using Python

Tags: python, pandas, data-visualization, visualization

How do I visualize the below dataframe in Python. I wish to visualize the data in a bar chart where the Year_of_Release is the X axis, Global_Sales is the bar height & the genre is the legend. The bar has to be colored separately for each Genre. I have shared a sample of what I'm looking for. The sample graph was created on R using GGPLOT.

Below are the column definitions

Year_of_Release - Year of Release

Genre - Game Genre

Global_Sales - Revenue made by a Genre in that given year

Images of the data frame & desired Bar plot as as below

Data Frame:

[image]

Desired Bar Chart:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please always include a language tag when asking questions here. And note that Python doesn't natively have dataframes. If you're also using pandas, please include that tag as well.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the code below to plot that you need...

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,6))
sns.set_theme(style="darkgrid")
ax=sns.barplot(x="Year_of_Release", y="Global_Sales", hue="Genre", dodge=False, palette="rocket", data=df)
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
ax.grid(True)
ax.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

**Plot**

with dummy data
...

[image]